# How to improve the performance of my graph coloring model in MiniZinc?

Tags: optimization, constraint-programming, minizinc

I have created a model for solving the graph coloring problem in MiniZinc:

```
include "globals.mzn";

int: n_nodes;               % Number of nodes
int: n_edges;               % Number of edges
int: domain_ub;             % Number of colors
array[int] of int: edges;   % All edges of graph as a 1D array
array[1..n_edges, 1..2] of int: edges2d = array2d(1..n_edges, 1..2, edges);

array[1..n_nodes] of var 1..domain_ub: colors;

constraint forall (i in 1..n_edges) (colors[edges2d[i,1]] != colors[edges2d[i,2]]);

solve :: int_search(colors, dom_w_deg, indomain_random)
    satisfy;
```

In order to tackle big problems (around 400-500 nodes), I start with an upper bound of the number of colors and solve successive satisfaction problems decrementing the number by one till it becomes unsatisfiable or times out. This method gives me decent results.

In order to improve my results, I added symmetry breaking constraints to the above model:

```
constraint colors[1] = 1;
constraint forall (i in 2..n_nodes) ( colors[i] in 1..max(colors[1..i-1])+1 );
```

This, however, brings down my results both speed-wise and quality-wise.

Why is my model performing badly after adding the additional constraints? How should I go about adding the symmetry breaking constraints?

Comment: You can test different search strategies what works better (`indomain_random` might not be so good with the symmetry breaking). Also, what is the upper bound of colors (`domain_ub`)? If it's  a planar graph, 4 colors will suffice.

Comment: @hakank This is not a planar graph. I tested with different search strategies and even though `input_order` with `indomain_min` gave slightly better results, it was still not comparable to when I did not add the additional constraints.

Comment: @hakank I am using `minizinc` Python package to run the model. For `domain_ub`, I run a loop starting with the max degree of the graph and decrementing it till I reach unsatisfiability or it times out.

Comment: OK, then it would help if you can add a (small) data set where this behaviour is shown.

Comment: @hakank Unfortunately, I run into this issue for large data sets. I am trying to recreate the issue in a small data set with no luck so far.

Answer (score 3):

For symmetry breaking for cases where the values are fully symmetric, I would recommend the [`seq_precede_chain`](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.3/en/lib-globals.html#index-55) constraint, which breaks that symmetry. As commented by @hakank, using `indomain_random` is probably not a good idea when used with symmetry breaking, `indomain_min` is a safer choice.

For graph coloring in general, it may help performance to run a clique-finding algorithm, and post `all_different` constraints over each cliques found. That would have to be done when generating a minizinc program for each instance. For comparison, see the [Gecode graph coloring example which uses pre-computed cliques](https://github.com/Gecode/gecode/blob/develop/examples/graph-color.cpp).

Comment: My first attempt at symmetry constraints used `seq_precede_chain(colors)`. However, this did not help much. From my observations, the fastest way to get a solution is to add just the main constraints and specify the search strategy. I will also look into clique finding algorithms. Thanks for the example!

Comment: With symmetry breaking, it is always the issue that symmetry breaking constraints might not work well in conjunction with the used search strategy, but always worth trying.

Comment: I now realize that what I am looking for is a way to dynamically add symmetry constraints during the search. For example, if the search uses `first-fail` strategy, then when the solver picks the second variable to look at, it should dynamically be constrained to have only 2 values, as explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVsFFVOomHw&feature=youtu.be&t=1229). Is there a way to do this in MiniZinc?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I was working on the same problem and I wanted to write what I found about this topic that maybe it will be useful to someone in the future.

To improve the model the solution is to use symmetry breaking constraint, as you did, but in Minizinc there is a global constraint called `value_precede` which can be used in this case.

```
% A new color J is only allowed to appear after colors 0..J-1 have been seen before (in any order)
constraint forall(j in 1..n-1)(value_precede(j, j+1, map));
```

Changing the search heuristics the result does not improve much, I have tried different configurations and the best results are obtained using `dom_w_deg` and `indomain_min` (compared to my data files).

Another way to improve the results is to accept any good enough solution that's less than the number of colours in the domain.
But this model does not always lead to obtaining the optimal result.

```
include "globals.mzn";

int: n; % Number of nodes
int: e; % Number of edges
int: maxcolors = 17; % Domain of colors

array[1..e,1..2] of int: E; % 2d array, rows = edges, 2 cols = nodes per edge
array[0..n-1] of var 0..maxccolors: c;   % Color of node n

constraint forall(i in 1..e)(c[E[i,1]] != c[E[i,2]] ); % Two linked nodes have diff color
constraint c[0] == 0; % Break Symmetry, force fist color == 0

% Big symmetry breaker. A new color J is only allowed to appear after colors
% 0..J-1 have been seen before (in any order)
constraint forall(i in 0..n-2)( value_precede(i,i+1, c)  );

% Ideally solve would minimize(max(c)), but that's too slow, so we accept any good
% enough solution that's less equal our heuristic "maxcolors"
constraint max(c) <= maxcolors;
solve :: int_search(c, dom_w_deg, indomain_min, complete) satisfy;

output [ show(max(c)+1), "\n", show(c)]
```

A clear and complete explanation can be found here:
https://maxpowerwastaken.gitlab.io/model-idiot/posts/graph_coloring_and_minizinc/